# How do you script a unordered list to display data upon hover?

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

It's kind of hard to explain. So, I'll give an example.

http://www.genesee.edu/

This is my college's website. At the very bottom, there's an area for contact information. If you hover your mouse over it, it displays the phone numbers and stuff for that location.

I'm trying to figure out what this feature is called, and how I can script it into my website.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, they're using Bootstrap `Navs`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

With Bootstrap `Tabs`:

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

From that page's [`root.min.20120719035512.js`](http://www.genesee.edu/cms/home/includes/themes/swoosh/compiled/root.min.20120719035512.js):

```
function hideCampusAddress() {
    $("div.campusInfo").each(function() {
        $(this).hide()
    })
}

function toggleCampusAddress(b) {
    var a = "div#pop_" + b;
    hideCampusAddress();
    $("div#showCampusInfo").html(function() {
        return $(a).html()
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul#campus-selector li a").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            nameArr = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
            toggleCampusAddress(nameArr[1]);
            $(this).parents().siblings().each(function() {
                $(this).children().removeClass("active")
            });
            $(this).addClass("active")
        })
    });
    hideCampusAddress();
    toggleCampusAddress("Batavia");
    $("#sel_Batavia").toggleClass("active");
});
```

And from the page source:

```
<h3>Locations</h3>
<ul id="campus-selector" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/albion/" id="sel_Albion">Albion</a>
    <div id="pop_Albion" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">456 West Ave Albion, NY 14411</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 589-4936</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:albion@genesee.edu">albion@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/arcade/" id="sel_Arcade">Arcade</a>
    <div id="pop_Arcade" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">25 Edward Street</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 492-5265</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:arcade@genesee.edu">arcade@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/about/" id="sel_Batavia">Batavia</a>
    <div id="pop_Batavia" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">One College Rd Batavia, NY 14020</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 343-0055 | (866) CALL-GCC</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/dansville/" id="sel_Dansville">Dansville</a>
    <div id="pop_Dansville" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">31 Clara Barton St</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 335-7820</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:dansville@genesee.edu">dansville@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/lima/" id="sel_Lima">Lima</a>
    <div id="pop_Lima" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">7285 Gale Rd</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 582-1226</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:lima@genesee.edu">lima@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/medina/" id="sel_Medina">Medina</a>
    <div id="pop_Medina" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">11470 Maple Ridge Rd</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 798-1688</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:medina@genesee.edu">medina@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard"><a class="org" href="/warsaw/" id="sel_Warsaw">Warsaw</a>
    <div id="pop_Warsaw" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">115 Linwood Avenue</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 786-3010</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:warsaw@genesee.edu">warsaw@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard" id="footer_dl"><a class="org" href="/depts/dl/" id="sel_Online">eLearning</a>
    <div id="pop_Online" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">eLearning</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 345-6969</div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:online@genesee.edu">online@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="vcard" id="footer_hs"><a class="org" href="/depts/ace/" id="sel_HighSchool">High School</a>
    <div id="pop_HighSchool" class="campusInfo">
      <div class="adr">Accelerated College Enrollment (ACE)</div>
      <div class="tel">(585) 345-6801 </div>
      <div class="email"><a href="mailto:ACE@genesee.edu">ACE@genesee.edu</a></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="showCampusInfo"></div>
```